# Google map with geolocation and route info facility on a mobile website

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, mobile-website

What is the good way to add a google map with geolocation and route info facility for a mobile website which is for iphone and Android?

I want like when user will open the web page he will get the permission message to use his location and when he will permit the map will load on the page with user's location.

Here is the explanation of process https://cacoo.com/diagrams/rlKiNG7rezQOeTlC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try out the [jquery mobile google maps plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/). See the jQuery mobile examples.